# Can I cast a const member of parent as a non-const in child class in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a parent class with a const pointer to a memory location. This parent is meant to be sort-of-interface in intent, but practically it is an implementation class; althoug it is used as an interface. The parent is also not meant to modify the memory location.

**Restrictions**:
I cannot use polymorphic inheritance. No virtual functions, absolutely.
Ideally, I would like to retain the function calls as is otherwise it would break existing code.
Functions may use either ConstedInterface/NonConstedImplementation  pointer or reference as an argument to access a NonConstedImplementation class.

**Pseudo C++ code:**

```
template <type T>
class ConstedInterface{
public:
T const& operator[](int index) const 
{ return memloc[index];}

private:
 const T* const memloc;
};

template <type T>
class ConstedImplementation: public ConstedInterface<T> //Allows non-mutable access to memloc
{

using ConstedInterface<T>::memloc;
};

template <type T>
class NonConstedImplementation: public ConstedInterface<T> //Allows mutable access to memloc
{
using ConstedInterface<T>::memloc; //Any way to make this non const?
using ConstedInterface<T>::operator[];

//Add a non-const index accessor 
T& operator[](int index) const 
{ return memloc[index];}
};
```

At this point the compiler complains that I am trying to access a const member through a non-const function. I can change this by adding a const_cast in NonConstedImplementation::operator[]

```
T& operator[](int index) const 
{ return const_cast<T&>(memloc[index]);}
```

This resolves the problem. But if I have 100 such functions, then I need to add a const_cast to all of them. Lets assume I do that for NonConstedImplementation class, but I have more specialized classes derived from all these three classes. And it is a pretty large hierarchy. And even if I fix all functions in NonConstedImplementation , I need to do it for all the child classes of NonConstedImplementation too.

Is there a neater way to do this with minimal impact on other inherited classes, and preferably zero impact on the code using these classes.
I know `std::conditional` is one possible solution but it will require me to add a template parameter and the cascade of changes is too much.

Comment: Honestly, const data members are just not worth the trouble.

Comment: Sounds to me like `ConstedInterface` should just be an interface, and not be responsible for actually implementing the `memloc` member.

Comment: If you cannot use *dynamic* polymorphic inheritance, can you instead use *static* polymorphism (compile-time polymorphism)?  q.v. [Polymorphic Ducks](https://mropert.github.io/2017/11/30/polymorphic_ducks/) by Mathieu Ropert.

Comment: Don't make data members `const`. Make them `private` and provide a `public` getter to maintain invariance. In your case, you could also add a `protected` non-const getter which, I think, solves all your problems.

Comment: You haven't shown how `memloc` is actually initialized, so it's *possible* that `const_cast` won't be Undefined Behavior. But it likely is UB, and even if it isn't this solution introduces a significant maintenance problem. It's brittle (it can be broken by changes to unrelated parts of the class) and should be an instant huge red flag to anyone reading the code. In my opinion. this approach would probably never pass most competent code reviews and shouldn't be used in real production code.

Comment: There are several errors in this example. `template <type T>` should probably be `template <class T>`. `memloc` can't be `private` or it is inaccessible from `NonConstedImplementation`. Please show real C++ code when possible, or at least remove errors unrelated to your question.

Comment: I think, the easiest solution would be to have base class a non-const protected member. Const interface than has only non-modifying functions, while non-const has both modifying and non-modifying. (To save on typing, one can put non-modifying function into base)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It is currently an interface, and the proposed changes violate many design guidleines; but we need to reduce memory footprint of the binary, hence we are considering eliminating the VPTRs for this hierachy. memloc doesn't exist in the current design. The memory is allocated in the implementation classes but to make this change, we are storing a pointer to it in the base class. The pointer is passed "upwards" via constructor chaining. I avoided showing that for simplicity. Maybe I will add that to the example code.